# Apply machine learning model to another dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to get into machine learning, and I've been following this tutorial:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/05/classification-algorithms-in-python-heart-attack-prediction-and-analysis/

Near the end, we split the dataset into training and testing using train_test_split

```
x = data3.drop("output", axis=1)
y = data3["output"]
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3)
```

That is, we use the same dataset for training and testing, 70% for training and 30% for testing.

But how can I use another dataset to test my model ?

One scenario came to mind: "You trained your model in 250 patients, now test it against these 3 patients that we have, so we can see the chances of them having a heart attack".

How can I, instead of splitting the data, use another csv/dataframe as a test ? Assuming this test data has the same format as the train, just fewer rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3)` only divides data into training and testing set. After training the model on training data, you can use your other data for testing too. This function is mainly for splitting current data and you can use any data for testing purposes. You just have to make sure the attributes and the type are same as the training data. If you have to test on 3 patients, all you have to do is to pass the patients data into `model.predict()` function as a dataframe or an array depends on data.

Answer (score 0):

Just as you load one dataframe from a file:

```
data1 = pd.read_csv("heart.csv")
```

If you had two separate data files, you'd load them into separate data files and skip the `train_test_split` step.

```
train_df = pd.read_csv("heart_train.csv")
test_df = pd.read_csv("heart_test.csv")
```

Since the two dataframes are already separate, you just have to make sure you do any cleaning and pre-processing steps on both of them, including removal of the target variable (y).